# How can I pass the exit status of a command from one recipe to another in a multi-host Beaker job?

Tags: beaker-testing

I am doing multi-host testing in Beaker, where one recipe is waiting for a command in another recipe to complete. I want to vary the behaviour based on whether the command in the other recipe succeeded or failed.

Is there any way I can communicate the exit status of a command from one recipe to another?

(Based on a mailing list discussion from March 2014.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beaker doesn't provide any mechanism for passing arbitrary data between recipes in a recipe set. There is only [rhts-sync-set](https://beaker-project.org/docs/user-guide/task-environment.html#rhts-sync-set)/[rhts-sync-block](https://beaker-project.org/docs/user-guide/task-environment.html#rhts-sync-block) for synchronization.

However you can still (ab)use those to achieve what you want. The trick is to use two separate sync states. Let's call them `CMD_SUCCEEDED` and `CMD_FAILED` (use more specific names if you want).

The first recipe sets `CMD_SUCCEEDED` if the command succeeded or `CMD_FAILED` if the command failed.

```
do_something_important
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    rhts-sync-set -s CMD_SUCCEEDED
else
    rhts-sync-set -s CMD_FAILED
fi
```

Then your other recipe can wait on *either* state (by passing two `-s` options) and then test which one was reached (by passing `--timeout 0`):

```
rhts-sync-block -s CMD_SUCCEEDED -s CMD_FAILED $CLIENTS
if rhts-sync-block -s CMD_SUCCEEDED --timeout 0 $CLIENTS ; then
    # command succeeded
else
    # command failed
fi
```

(This idea was originally suggested by Nick Coghlan.)